# Select text-replacement without adding a space?

Tags: text

I have set up Lion text replacement to replace a three-letter short-code with my full email address. It works great, and I recommend you all do it. :-)

But - in order to confirm the auto-replacement, I need to press the space key (similar in iOS). Often for web-forms, etc. I don't want that space to be there.

Does anyone know if there is a keystroke which will select the suggested text auto-replacement without adding a space?

Comment: I don’t know how to do this with Lion’s text replacements, but you might want to consider [TextExpander](http://www.smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/), which performs a similar task. You don’t need to add a trailing space to open a snippet, which is what you’re looking for, right?

e.g. my email address in TextExpander is set off with the shortcut `;g`, no space required.

Comment: Alex - please write your answer as an "answer". ;-)

Comment: sorry, I didn’t think that qualified as a proper answer, more a suggestion for a workaround if an answer wasn’t found. I’ve put it again below.

Comment: i'm interested in this too .. would be nice if you could use a special key (right arrow key maybe)  to auto complete without adding a space

Answer (score 2):

I don’t know how to do this with Lion’s text replacements, but you might want to consider TextExpander, which performs a similar task. You don’t need to add a trailing space to open a snippet, which is what you’re looking for, right? e.g. my email address in TextExpander is set off with the shortcut `;g`, no space required.

[Duped from comments per dan8394’s request]